# where can i get the spring framework 3.0 distribution?

Tags: spring, download

has anyone been able to download the spring framework 3.0.0.M4 release from the spring source site... (or can you provide an alternative download page)?

http://www.springsource.org/download

am I missing something..., the site is giving me the runaround...

when i get to the "Spring Community Downloads" page and choose spring from the LHS menu... I get no download link...

Comment: http://www.springsource.com/download/community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using maven, add this to your `<repositories>` in your pom.xml:

```
<repository>
  <id>spring-milestone</id>
  <name>Spring Portfolio Milestone Repository</name>
  <url>http://s3.amazonaws.com/maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
</repository>
```

and declare your spring dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>3.0.0.M4</version>
</dependency>
```

For others artifcats, use the [Spring Maven artifact URL](http://s3browse.com/explore/maven.springframework.org/milestone) for browsing.

More on Spring's maven repositories in this [article](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/09/18/maven-artifacts-2/).

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. Go to http://s3.amazonaws.com/dist.springframework.org/release/SPR/spring-framework-3.0.5.RELEASE.zip
2. When you hit the URL, your download for jar files starts automatically
3. After unzipping, there is a folder called `dist` which contains the following jar files for spring 3.0.5

   - org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.context.support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.instrument-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.jms-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.oxm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.transaction-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
   - org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar

**NOTE** : You can download any release of spring framwork just by modifying the release version to **3.0.1** or **3.2.5** (any other versions according to your need)in the above mentioned URL

Comment: this is the most direct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The repository answer is probably the best answer, but if you want to just build it yourself here are some steps to do that.

http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/03/building-spring-3/

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/

Depending on what you need, you can use maven central or spring EBR. The above link compares the repositories, and also explains how to get milestone, release, as well as snapshot of springframework.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what he is asking for, there are many Spring external jars that are needed, for example of an import he maybe using:

```
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;


Some Jars that might be needed are:
org.springframework.aop-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.2.jar
...and over 20 more, where does one download these?

searching individually, here is one location:

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.beans/3.0.2
```

Here is another location you may wish to use:
http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/library/version/detail?name=org.springframework.spring&version=3.2.3.RELEASE&searchType=librariesBySymbolicName&searchQuery=org.springframework

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please use the Answer feature only for actual answers. If you want to improve the original question just edit it (`Improve this question` link)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a build system like Maven. You can read about it [here](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) if you want to learn more.

Then in your `pom.xml` add the following coordinates:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

You can check out all the versions of the Spring Framework (now referred to as Spring Core) at [MVN Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core)